# What is a good way to differentiate between Jboss Web Apps and Web Services?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, jboss

I'm currently managing web app and web service container settings in a JBoss environment.  The way my code is currently distinguishing between the two is by the name of the WAR (appending wa for a web app).  Is there a feature built into JBoss that will make this determination for me on a different basis?

Comment: Aren't they all the same thing, just responding to different protocols?

Comment: mostly... I'm not sure there is a clear distinction.  I'm currently using SOAP messaging to communicate with web services, whereas web apps are simple HTML calls.